# How Do I OrderBy ItemChildCount in a ContentQueryWebPart

Tags: sharepoint-designer, content-query-web-part

I'm trying to order items in a content query web part from a discussion board by the number of replies to each item (ItemChildCount). Is there an easy way to go about this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to apply Grouping and Sorting for ItemChildCount field

include explicitly this field using [AdditionalGroupAndSortFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.additionalgroupandsortfields%28v=office.12%29.aspx) property

```
<property name="AdditionalGroupAndSortFields" type="string" >ItemChildCount</property>
```

and select for List Type: Discussion Board and for Content Type: Discussion (as shown on picture below)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't seem to get it to work. I've followed your advice and still return an error. If I declare fields other than ItemChildCount the sorting works fine. It's something to do w/ the ItemChildCount that breaks the ability to order by that field. Any other help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can anyone else shed some light on this one?

Comment: @E7AD - What is your error?